# In Chrome, can I hide certain bookmarked links from appearing in autocomplete?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks, autocomplete

Let's say I have two folders with bookmarks:

- Current project

  - www.somenewwiki.com
- Old project

  - www.someoldwiki.com

After I type in my URL bar: "wiki".

I will get two auto-complete options: `somenewwiki` and `someoldwiki`.

Is there a way for Chrome to ignore the "old project" folder when trying to suggest links? I only want to get `somenewwiki` as a suggestion.